# Python How to fuse road segmentation data from an image to AOA data(distance, angle)

Tags: python, computer-vision

[image]

I have road segmentation data which is highlighted by the semi-transparent blue color.
It is an Numpy matrix with 0 means not road, 1 represents road.

I also have AOA data which tells the distance and angle between the camera and the Human block.

Now my question is: how can I fuse these 2 types of data together so that my DC motor car knows how it can drive to the target human via the detected road segmentation?

```
aoa_data = aoa.get_data()
# aoa_data : {"distance": 2.3, "angle": 37.5}
road_seg = nn.get_road_seg()
# road_seg is a matrix which contains 1 for road, 0 for non-road pixels.
```

ps:
Please let me know if this is the correct place to post this topic, thanks.

Comment: crosspost: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75802028/python-how-to-fuse-road-segmentation-data-from-an-image-to-aoa-datadistance-an

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Franva, but I'm afraid that *Unbounded Design Questions* are off-topic because there are many ways to solve any given design problem. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Comment: There are potentially many ways to achieve what you want.  So unfortunately, this question is unanswerable without many more specifics and narrower scope.

Comment: Hi @Ben thanks for your comments. I have added some pseudo code to make it more specific.  Please let me if you need any more specific information. thanks.